# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: bash, powershell, docker, shell, scripting

I am running below script and getting error

```
#!/bin/bash
webproxy="webproxy-test-01"
webproxycurl="curl -k -s https://localhost:\${nginx_https_port}/HealthCheckService"
sudo docker exec $webproxy sh -c \'$webproxycurl\'
```

Here is the error.

```
-k: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-k: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is the command which works on shell prompt

```
$sudo docker exec webproxy-test-01 sh -c 'curl -k -s https://localhost:${nginx_https_port}/HealthCheckService'
HEALTHCHECK_OK
```

Could someone please help me with the error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess `${nginx_https_port}` is a variable, why are you escaping it ??

Comment: yes, it's an environment variable! I will try to use it without that \

Comment: If i dont escape it....it skips the entire env var ${nginx_https_port}

Comment: I think it is something related with the docker, because actually in a normal linux bash I don't need to escape neither the `$` nor the single quote `'` . I would show you in an answer, if you want to

Comment: Try this: `sudo docker exec $webproxy sh -c "$webproxycurl"`

Comment: sudo docker exec $webproxy sh -c "$webproxycurl" works....thanks atul and roberto :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```sh
sudo docker exec $webproxy sh -c "$webproxycurl"
```

Also, as a side note, do not run docker in `sudo`.

- Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist:

  ```
   sudo groupadd docker
  ```
- Add the connected user "$USER" to the docker group. Change the user name to match your preferred user if you do not want to use your current user:

  ```
   sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
  ```
- Either do a `newgrp docker` or log out/in to activate the changes to groups.
- You can use

  ```
   docker run hello-world
  ```

  to check if you can run docker without sudo.

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/477554/307057) for more details.